# Reading First and Last Line of txt File; Fastest Method and Subprocess Troubleshooting

Tags: python, subprocess

I've got a bunch of large text files to read the first and last line of. What would be the best method of doing it? I read that using subprocesses would be quicker, but can't seem to get it to work (I'm quite daft regarding these)

```
line = subprocess.check_output(['tail', '-1', "A:/Desktop/TempData/Yes.txt"])
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

AFAIK, the error is because the file isn't in the directory.
 In very basic terms, how would I go about solving this? (remember, I'm dumb). I tried the following code, but it still doesn't work.

```
import os


def makemydir(whatever):
    try:
        os.makedirs(whatever)
    except OSError:
        pass
    os.chdir(whatever)


makemydir('A:/Desktop/TempData/')
```

Would this still be the fastest method? Should I consider multithreading?

Comment: Best not to ask more than one question in a post...

Comment: first check if you have file `A:/Desktop/TempData/Yes.txt` on your disk. Second check if you have program `tail` - it is preinstalled on Linux but rather not on Windows. You can also get full path to `tail`. You can also use `python` to open file, reads lines and get first and last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tail](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix)) is a linux command that displays the last lines of a file. The code you posted tries to invoke that command outside of python and read its output.

Because it's a native linux binary and you're on Windows, python cannot find the command "tail", which causes the error message you saw. You need to install something like mingw or git bash to get the "tail" program installed.

If you want to do it using python only, I suggest opening the file, using file.seek to read from the end of the file and search backwards for where the last line starts.